# Increase Scrollback Buffer in Putty

Tags: putty

I'm running Putty on Windows and can't find an option to increase the size of the scrollback buffer .  It seems set at about 4 pages of text.

Am I missing something?

Comment: http://dag.wieers.com/blog/content/improving-putty-settings-on-windows

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can increase the scrollback by selecting the *Window* options category  and changing the *[Lines of scrollback](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback)* option.

Comment: i think it defaults to 200; when i configure a session profile for PuTTY on my systems i usually change this to 5000 or more.

Comment: Ah!  I was looking at the option nodes under Window, not realizing that Window itself has options :-)

Comment: @quack: I can see how to save the config changes per session.  Is there a way to save a new default for any session?

Comment: @Eric: i'm pretty sure you can alter the config of the *Default* session in the same way you change it for any other session -- load the Default session, make your changes, save it as the Default session.

Answer (score 10):

First load the session, then go to the *Window* category in the left pane and change *Lines of scrollback* to say, 20000. Go back to the *Session* category and save it.

Note: you must load the session for it to save!

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple load your required session and change your desired scroll back value on window option then click on Save button.

Comment: Can you clarify how this is different from the other two answers?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking to increase the scroll-back buffer, but when starting a session from the windows terminal. For this, you need to change the default settings, [like so](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter4.html#config-saving) :

*To save your default settings: first set up the settings the way you want them saved. Then come back to the Session panel. Select the ‘Default Settings’ entry in the saved sessions list, with a single click. Then press the ‘Save’ button.*

Comment: Oh, you're my rescue with this stubborn putty interface. Thanks!